# Lost neutral from main to entire cabin

Tags: electrical

Lost neutral to entire smal cabin, have disconnected all black and whites from bus bars, shows 121 volts at main from both sides to common, new main breaker.
Wired one single breaker to outside outlet, one outlet enclosed in flex pvc. Have power black to ground but nothing black to common. Any help here greatly apreciated.

Comment: With a lost neutral you need to find where the connection is lost/broken.  Main breaker has nothing to do with neutral connections, the neutral wire bypasses that breaker and connects directly to the neutral bus bar.  You will want power disconnected before that panel before playing around in it, which I hope you did before changing the main breaker.  You have connection at the feeder wires, but do you have connection from the bus?  Picture of the panel will help.

Comment: Call the power company **_NOW_** and have them come fix it. Odds are exceedingly good that it's on their end. They'll also know how to fix it without any of their employees dying.

Answer (score 2):

### Call your power company on their emergency/outage number!

Since from your description, it appears your neutral is dead at or before the main panel, you need to call your power company on their power outage hotline and tell *them* that you have an outage that needs a truck to fix.  This is because the problem is just as likely to be on their side as anywhere else, and if it is a power company problem, getting a truck sent your way is the only way it will *ever* get fixed.